# Combining AutoName and multiple values with Python 3.9 Enum

Tags: python, enums

I'm working with Python's Enum classes (in Python 3.9), and trying to combine a couple of things from their [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html).  The ["Planet" example class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#planet) demonstrates a tuple (mass,radius) as the value of the enum members, and also setting additional member attributes based on that as the values are passed to an overridden `__init__()` method.  However, the "value" of the enum members winds up being that tuple.
The [AutoName class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#using-automatic-values) shows using the enum.auto() helper function and an overridden `_generate_next_value_()` method to use the member's name as the value.
And in general, overriding the `__new__()` method seems to be the only way to set the value attribute of a member.  I'm having trouble combining these three things.

What I'd like is something like Planet, except where the "value" is changed to "name", as in AutoName(), so that Planet.MERCURY is "MERCURY", not the tuple.  But in an override of `__new__()`, there seems to be no way to know what the "name" of the member being created is, so you can't set "value" to it.  And with "auto()", there seems to be no way to provide additional values, like the (mass, radius) info from Planet.  I'd hoped to do something like this (assuming the existence of the AutoName class):

```py
class Planet(AutoName):
    MERCURY = auto(3.303e+23, 2.4397e6)  # doesn't work
    VENUS = (auto(), 4.869e+24, 6.0518e6)  # doesn't work
```

Is there a way to combine the tuple for the enum value with some way of also changing the member value, as auto() does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible using the stdlib `Enum`, but is possible using the `aenum`<sup>1</sup> library:

```
from aenum import Enum

class AutoName(Enum):
    def _generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last, *args, **kwds):
        return (name, ) + args

class Planet(AutoName):
    _init_ = 'value mass radius'
    MERCURY = 3.303e+23, 2.4397e6
    VENUS = 4.869e+24, 6.0518e6
```

`_init_` serves two purposes:

- specifies what attributes to save the given values to
- if more attributes are specified than given, call `_generate_next_value_` in an attempt to create the missing values

--

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.